# Can servlets have extensions?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I have a page http://domain.com/servlets/projecta?action=cust_active

but need to provide a link to the same place with an extension (like .jsp or something).

Is there a way to add an extension to this, but have it still load the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need multiple URL mappings for your servlet in web.xml.  Assuming that your existing servlet is mapped to `projecta` like this:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/projecta</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

You might need:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/projecta</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/projecta.ext</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Also see this in case your servlet version is different: [many url-pattern for the same servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995353/many-url-pattern-for-the-same-servlet)