# Spring MVC url-pattern syntax

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Trying to add a restful web service call to an existing Spring 3.11 MVC application, but the app has a url mapping in web.xml for spring like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So everything basically needs to end in .html

I would like for my web service to not have to do that - ideally by using a unique context/subfolder for my web services, such as /restful for example.

But I am not sure how to get it to work...

So if my controller was like this:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="restful/test/{test}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(@PathVariable String test) 
    {   
        return "OK"+test;
    }
```

And I wanted to access it by: localhost/blah/restful/test/text (no .html anywhere, and where blah is the application context) how should I handle the url-pattern in the web.xml -- without interfering with anything already existing in the app?

When I add another url-pattern like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And try to access localhost/blah/restful/test/text, I get a 404 error.

The other part of the web-xml for servlet looks like this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

And the view resolver in that spring-mvc.xml file is like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [many url-pattern for the same servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995353/many-url-pattern-for-the-same-servlet)

Comment: I realize it's not actually related to trying to get multiple patterns anymore - it's either the pattern syntax itself or something else in this app's config causing the problem

Comment: it's all your web.xml i think you miss some thing in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default MVC configuration, given

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="restful/test/{test}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

you should be trying to access `localhost/blah/restful/restful/test/text` (note the double `/restful`).

Spring MVC, in requests with a path mapping (see [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) chapter 12), tries to extract the path segment that was matched by the container (the first `/restful` in this case) and therefore use the rest `/restful/test/text` to find an appropriate handler (your `@Controller`'s `@RequestMapping` annotated method).

I would simply remove the `restful` part from your `@RequestMapping`. You'd be left with

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/{test}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

which would be able to handle a request to `/localhost/blah/restful/test/text`.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem!

Answer (score -1):

Do you have tried this ?

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or just in a different order like this (because order should matter):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: also in different order by first example?