# url-pattern in web.xml not recognising multiple url

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

I have web.xml like this :

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyDisplayCourse</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.itn.controller.MyDisplayCourse</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

and servlet-mapping for the servlet is:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyDisplayCourse</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/admin/displaystudent</url-pattern>    
    <url-pattern>/displaystudent</url-pattern>    
 </servlet-mapping>
```

When i use :

```
 <url-pattern>/displaystudent</url-pattern>
```

It finds the servlet MyDisplayCourse, but when i use append /admin/

```
 <url-pattern>/admin/displaystudent</url-pattern>
```

This shows 404 error code in my web app. Can someone help me why   doesn't support url like /admin/displaystudent but supports only single url like /displaystudent only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [many url-pattern for the same servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995353/many-url-pattern-for-the-same-servlet)

Comment: this is not the question i am asking. i want to use /admin/displaystudent instead of /displaystudent only.

Comment: How do you access your application? Can you provide the URL as well?

Comment: Both the urls should work fine. Can you create a sample project which can recreate the issue ?

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer 
localhost:8080/practiceweb/admin/displaystudent

Comment: @Veeram second one didn't work.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in the post to tell what issue it is. May be it is something else that is causing this issue.Like I said please try to create a sample project demonstrating the issue.

Comment: i have a project, what do you need from the project?

Comment: I need a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also any error you see in server logs

Comment: https://github.com/gautamvishal00/demoproject/tree/master/PracticeWeb
see the project here.

Comment: Thanks for providing the project. I'm positive that `@WebServlet` annotation on your controller class is conflicting with `web.xml` url pattterns. Can you try removing the `@WebServlet` annotation and then try accessing the urls ?.

Comment: no it is not. @Veeram , it is mapping error. Checked those things like hundred times now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with `url-pattern`

the issue is with your code in DisplayStudent.java

replace

`RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("StudentTable.jsp");`

with

`RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/StudentTable.jsp");`

[ServletRequestSpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String))

> If the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the
>   current context root

otherwise it will concatinate with relative path in your case '/admin/StudentTable.jsp'

following code is implementation of [getRequestDispatcher](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/io.undertow/undertow-servlet/1.2.10.Final/io/undertow/servlet/spec/HttpServletRequestImpl.java#878)

```
@Override
public RequestDispatcher getRequestDispatcher(final String path) {
String realPath;
 if (path.startsWith("/")) {
    realPath = path;
 } else {
    String current = exchange.getRelativePath();
    int lastSlash = current.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (lastSlash != -1) {
        current = current.substring(0, lastSlash + 1);
    }
    realPath = CanonicalPathUtils.canonicalize(current + path);
 }
 return new RequestDispatcherImpl(realPath, servletContext);
}
```